Create dynamic adjust width list in xamarin forms
I want to create category list as attached images. Please provide solution how to achieve this.
As in image it is seen that there is not static column for each row. Category manage width itself.
If you have any insights or solutions, I’d love to hear from you!
Thanks in advance for your help!


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/xamarinshow/flexlayout-for-xamarinforms-explained

I use flexlayout. working properly
